# create content popup using colorbox

Tags: php, jquery, html, colorbox

I'm trying to make a content popup using colorbox.

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.colorbox').colorbox({
    inline:true,
   width: 640,
   height: 480
    });
});
</script> 

   </head>

<body>
<div style="display:none">
       <div id="popup">
            <?php echo $row["content"]; ?>
       </div>
</div>

<?php echo $row["content"]; ?> <a class='colorbox' href='#popup'><span>PopUp</span></a><br>
```

The problem is it always show the same content, example like this:

```
content one  PopUp
content two  PopUp
content three  PopUp
content four  PopUp
```

if i click content one PopUp link it will show "content one" in the colorbox although i click PopUp in content two or three or four it will always show "content one" in the colorbox, so how to fix this

I want to make if I click content one PopUp link it will show "content one", if I click content two PopUp link it will show "content two" and etc

======================================================================================

I can solve the problem but I have to change in

I change it into like this

```
<a class='colorbox' href='' onclick="$.fn.colorbox({ html:'<?php echo $row["comment"]; ?>'}); return false"><span>PopUp</span></a>
```

but how to change onclick function into jquery ? I don't want to use onclick..

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You should change the content of #popup after clicking each .colorbox . You may do this as below :

```
$(function(){

  $(".colorbox").on('click',function(){
      //do someting to change the content of #popup 
     //eg:
     //$("#popup").html(Math.rand())
  }).colorbox({
   inline:true,
   width: 640,
   height: 480
  });

});
```

Comment: thx.. I try to use `.html()` `.get().innerHTML()` `.val()` `.text()` to take the content inside <div> but it still give me same problem.. is i make a wrong code ? please help me..